# Sublime Text as an external editor for IAR EWB

Tags: ide, embedded, editor, sublimetext3, iar

I've been using IAR EWB for ARM quite a some time now, despite its fiddly IDE features such as code completion and jump to definitions etc. Sometimes they work in IAR editor but most of the times no. GCC+Eclipse is not an option for me as I'm using some pre-compiled library binaries that are only working with IAR. However, I noticed that it is possible to use an external editor with IAR.

For notepad++, the settings are,

In Embedded Workbench open this settings dialog - Tools > Options... > Editor > External Editor

- Tick 'Use External Editor'
- Type: Command Line Editor: C:\Program
  Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
- Arguments: "$FILE_PATH$"-n$CUR_LINE$ (These arguments will make notepad++ to jump to the particular line of code once when click a message in the IAR debug log)

I want to use Sublime text as the external editor with IAR. However, I was unable to find the arguments that I need to set in IAR to jump Sublime to a particular line of code once when an error message in the IAR debug window is clicked. Also, I do not want to use a new instance of sublime every time I clicked an error message in IAR build log, but reuse the instance that is already open.

Can anyone please point me out the relevant information?

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you. Did you manage to set/configure breakpoints though?

Comment: Well, No. I only used sublime as a text editor. Using IAREWB as my debugging-break pointing platform still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this link](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command-line), "$FILE_PATH$":$CUR_LINE$ should work for the arguments.

Whether Sublime starts a new instance is probably an application setting/preference.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It should be $FILE_PATH$:$CUR_LINE$ and the sublime automatically uses the current instance.